# unity3d-plugin for Teamcity seems doesn't see Unity folder

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine, teamcity

Greeting to everyone!

---

I'm trying to start use of Teamcity Unity3d-runner-plugin.
After Successful install on server and setup build step in project
, it is unable to build project.
Project doesn't start to work with warning message:

Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration. Please register a build agent or tweak the build configuration requirements.

on the Agent Requirement page there is a message

**agent** (disconnected)
**Incompatible runner**: Unity
**Unmet requirements**: unity.latest exists

---

Unity was installed in default folder, and works fine with no problem, that's why i can't understand, why does plugin can't see Unity env.parameter on agent.

Anyone know how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

The message (`unity.any exists`) suggests that it's not missing an environment variable (if it were missing a `%UNITY%` environment variable, it would be complaining about `env.UNITY`). Instead, it seems to be looking for a *build-agent property* called `unity.any`.

To define the `unity.any` build-agent property on your agent, edit the agent properties file at `<agent home>/conf/buildAgent.properties`, adding a line like this:

```
unity.any=1
```

(Read more [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Project+and+Agent+Level+Build+Parameters).)

I guess whoever wrote the plugin decided that there was no good way (for the TeamCity server) to tell if Unity is installed on any given agent, so the user (you) has to specify this by defining this agent property. Thus, by creating that line you're marking your agent as having Unity installed.

I *think* the properties file is reread periodically so you needn't restart the agent after you've added the line.

(If this helps, check the plugin's documentation and let the plugin author know if this information is missing.)