# TeamCity Unity plugin: Incompatible runner

Tags: unity-game-engine, teamcity

[I am using this plugin](https://github.com/mindcandy/Teamcity-unity3d-build-runner-plugin)

In Administration > Server Administration > Plugins List, I see unityRunner.

However, in the agent page > **Build Runners, Unity is not listed**, and in **Compatible Configurations**, my configuration is listed as incompatible, saying:

> Incompatible runner: Unity

[There is already a question but didn't resolve my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866926/unity3d-plugin-for-teamcity-seems-doesnt-see-unity-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Now JetBrains provides [Unity support plugin for TeamCity](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11453-unity-support). Please feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have Unity installed on the Agent. It should installed on one of the default location depending on the platform (Program Files or Applications). Please check it.

Comment: Unity 5.3.4f1 is installed.